# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable python3

Tags: python-3.x

this is the class i use inside my python file :

```
class SatelliteList(MenuList):

def __init__(self):
    MenuList.__init__(self, list=[], enableWrapAround=True, content=eListboxPythonMultiContent)
    if FHD_Res:
        self.l.setItemHeight(40)
        self.l.setFont(0, gFont('Regular', 27))
    else:
        self.l.setItemHeight(24)
        self.l.setFont(0, gFont('Regular', 20))

def setEntries(self, satelliteslist):
    res = []
    for x in satelliteslist:
        satparameter = x[0]
        satentry = []
        pos = int(satparameter.get('position'))
        if pos < 0:
            pos += 3600
        satentry.append(pos)
        color = None
        color_sel = None
        if satparameter.get('selected', False):
            color = 0
            color_sel = 65344
        backcolor = None
        backcolor_sel = None
        a = FHD_Res and 1050 or HD_Res and 700 or 430
        b = FHD_Res and 255 or HD_Res and 170 or 103
        if len(x) == 1:
            backcolor = 1644912
            backcolor_sel = 9466996
        if FHD_Res:
            satentry.append(MultiContentEntryText(pos=(0, 0), size=(a, 40), font=0, flags=RT_HALIGN_LEFT | RT_VALIGN_TOP, text=satparameter.get('name'), color=color, color_sel=color_sel, backcolor=backcolor, backcolor_sel=backcolor_sel, border_width=1, border_color=15792383))
        else:
            satentry.append(MultiContentEntryText(pos=(0, 0), size=(a, 24), font=0, flags=RT_HALIGN_LEFT | RT_VALIGN_TOP, text=satparameter.get('name'), color=color, color_sel=color_sel, backcolor=backcolor, backcolor_sel=backcolor_sel, border_width=1, border_color=15792383))
        pos = int(satparameter.get('position'))
        posStr = str(abs(pos) / 10) + '.' + str(abs(pos) % 10)
        if pos < 0:
            posStr = posStr + ' ' + 'West'
        if pos > 0:
            posStr = posStr + ' ' + 'East'
        if pos == 0:
            posStr = posStr + ' ' + 'Greenwich'
        if FHD_Res:
            satentry.append(MultiContentEntryText(pos=(a, 0), size=(b, 40), font=0, flags=RT_HALIGN_CENTER | RT_VALIGN_TOP, text=posStr, color=color, color_sel=color_sel, backcolor=backcolor, backcolor_sel=backcolor_sel, border_width=1, border_color=15792383))
        else:
            satentry.append(MultiContentEntryText(pos=(a, 0), size=(b, 24), font=0, flags=RT_HALIGN_CENTER | RT_VALIGN_TOP, text=posStr, color=color, color_sel=color_sel, backcolor=backcolor, backcolor_sel=backcolor_sel, border_width=1, border_color=15792383))
        res.append(satentry)
```

after running i got the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

line 905, in setEntries

for x in satelliteslist:

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

how can i fix that?

Comment: Run the debugger over it and find out, why `x` is `None` at some point of time when executing line 905.

Comment: @FlorianMetzger-Noel i ran pudb but it doesn't show anything

Comment: If it doesn't show anything, then your debugger is not working. A debugger is supposed to execute a program line by line and show all variable values in each step. If you know, what your program is supposed to do, then it's the perfect tool to find the spot where reality diverges from concept. Every good IDE has a built in debugger - I'm using PyCharm, which is free for students.